# How to pass through NotifyDataErrorInfo to a custom TextBox user control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox

#### The goal

I am practicing how to use the `TextBox` with different `Type` bound to the `Text` property.

There are a lot of threads out there covering this issue. However, I am missing some steps and will appreciate some support.

- input values must be in a specific range
- only positive integers are allowed
- `space`, `backspace` and `delete` keystrokes must be handled to prevent a `System.Windows.Data Error`

#### The setting

- Wpf application with .Net 8
- MVVM pattern; Dependency Injection
- CommunityToolkit.Mvvm
- a public [repository](https://github.com/karwenzman/StackOverflowSolution) on GitHub

The ***View*** contains three `TextBox` controls which are bound to the same property of the ***ViewModel***. The `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm` is used to reduce boilerplate.

```cs
    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(SaveDataButtonCommand))]
    [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(DiscardButtonCommand))]
    [NotifyDataErrorInfo]
    [Range(9, 999, ErrorMessage = "Value is out of range")]
    private int _intValue = 0;
    private int _backupIntValue = 0;
```

- ***Integer TextBox*** is a `TextBox` with standard behavior
- ***CustomTextBox*** is a `TextBox` where event handlers are added in `HomeView.xaml.cs`
- ***Custom IntegerTextBox*** is a custom user control named `IntegerTextBox.xaml` where event handlers are added and a `DependencyProperty` named `Value` is registered.

```xml
                <!-- Integer components -->
                <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Content="Integer TextBox" />
                <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"
                         MinWidth="200"
                         Text="{Binding IntValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" />
                <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Content="Custom TextBox" />
                <TextBox x:Name="CustomTextBox" 
                         Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3"
                         HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                         MinWidth="200"
                         Text="{Binding IntValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" />
                <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="5" Content="Custom IntegerTextBox" />
                <customControls:IntegerTextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="5"
                         MinWidth="200"
                         Value="{Binding IntValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" />
```

[image]

#### The steps to accomplish the goal

Within a `ResourceDictionary` the behavior of all `TextBox` controls is modified to remove the "red box" if a validation error was found and to show the validation error provided in the ***ViewModel***.

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <!-- Sets basic look of the TextBox -->
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2 1" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />

        <!-- Removes the red border around the TextBox, if validation found errors -->
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>      
        
        <!-- Enables the UI to show the error messages -->
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="3">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                        </Border>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Validation.Errors}" Margin="0 5 0 5">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding ErrorContent}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Additionally some events are added to validate the input while entering data into the `TextBox` control. The threads out there showed two solutions I like most. One is using `Regex` and the other is using `int.TryParse()`. To catch input like `space`, `backspace` and `delete` the event handlers are handling those.

```cs
    [GeneratedRegex("[^0-9]+")]
    private static partial Regex IntegerPositiveValuesOnlyRegex();

    // one option
    private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = IntegerPositiveValuesOnlyRegex().IsMatch(e.Text);
    }

    // another option
    private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !int.TryParse((sender as TextBox)!.Text,
            NumberStyles.Integer,
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            out int validInteger);
    }
```

#### The problems

Visualization of validation errors

1. the standard `TextBox` is working as intended (no red box; red error message beneath the control)
2. the `Custom TextBox` is working as intended (no red box; red error message beneath the control)
3. the `Custom IntegerTextBox` is showing the red box and not displaying the error message

Catching input

1. the standard `TextBox` is throwing a lot of exceptions and accepts all keys and values (however, that is the expected result)
2. the `Custom TextBox` is allowing integers only; no comma, no decimal point, no `-`; but pressing `space`, `backspace` or `delete` throws exceptions
3. the `Custom IntegerTextBox` is working as intended (no exceptions at all; only accepting positive integer values)

That is where I do need your help!

I am missing something, why the `TextBox` controls are acting differently. At least the `Custom IntegerTextBox` I would like to work as intended.

[image]

#### Unabridged code

The HomeView.xaml

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="SampleTextBoxValidation.Views.Screens.HomeView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleTextBoxValidation.Views.Screens" 
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:SampleTextBoxValidation.ViewModels" 
             xmlns:customControls="clr-namespace:SampleTextBoxValidation.Views.CustomControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModels:HomeViewModel}"
             d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <Border CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="MintCream" Padding="5">
        <DockPanel>
            <!-- *** The UI's title *** -->
            <Label DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               Content="Home Screen" 
               Margin="0 0 0 20"
               FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold">
            </Label>

            <!-- *** The UI's footer *** -->
            <Label DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               Content="Testing CommunityToolkit.Mvvm => ObservableValidator on several user controls." 
               Margin="0 20 0 0"
               FontSize="10" FontWeight="Bold">
            </Label>

            <!-- Button components -->
            <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Button  
                        Margin="15 20 15 5"
                        Command="{Binding DiscardButtonCommand}"
                        Content="Discard" />
                <Button 
                        Margin="15 20 15 5"
                        Command="{Binding LoadDataButtonCommand}"
                        Content="Load Data" />
                <Button 
                        Margin="15 20 15 5"
                        Command="{Binding SaveDataButtonCommand}"
                        Content="Save Data" />
            </StackPanel>

            <!-- *** The UI's body *** -->
            <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <!-- A column to seperate the user components on the left and right -->
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="10" MinWidth=" 20" />
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="10" MinWidth=" 20" />

                <!-- FirstName components -->
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="First Name" />
                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                         MinWidth="200"
                         Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" />
                <!-- LastName components -->
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Content="Last Name" />
                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"
                         MinWidth="200"
                         Text="{Binding LastName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" />

                <!-- Integer components -->
                <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Content="Integer TextBox" />
                <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"
                         MinWidth="200"
                         Text="{Binding IntValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" />
                <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Content="Custom TextBox" />
                <TextBox x:Name="CustomTextBox" 
                         Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3"
                         HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                         MinWidth="200"
                         Text="{Binding IntValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" />
                <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="5" Content="Custom IntegerTextBox" />
                <customControls:IntegerTextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="5"
                         MinWidth="200"
                         Value="{Binding IntValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" />

                <!-- Decimal components -->
                <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Content="Decimal StringFormat {0:C}" />
                <TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"
                         MinWidth="200"
                         Text="{Binding DecimalValue, StringFormat={}{0:C}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" />
                <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Content="Decimal As String" />
                <TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3"
                         MinWidth="200"
                         Text="{Binding DecimalValueAsString, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" />

                <!-- Double components -->
                <Label Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Content="Double StringFormat {0:F2}" />
                <TextBox Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1"
                         MinWidth="200"
                         Text="{Binding DoubleValue, StringFormat={}{0:F2}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" />
                <Label Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="3" Content="Double As String" />
                <TextBox Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="3"
                         MinWidth="200"
                         Text="{Binding DoubleValueAsString, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" />

            </Grid>
        </DockPanel>

    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

The HomeView.xaml.cs

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace SampleTextBoxValidation.Views.Screens;

public partial class HomeView : UserControl
{
    [GeneratedRegex("[^0-9]+")]
    private static partial Regex IntegerPositiveValuesOnlyRegex();

    public HomeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CustomTextBox.GotFocus += TextBox_GotFocus;
        CustomTextBox.PreviewTextInput += TextBox_PreviewTextInput;
        CustomTextBox.PreviewKeyUp += TextBox_PreviewKeyDown;
        CustomTextBox.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
    }

    private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Entered {nameof(TextBox_GotFocus)}");

        (sender as TextBox)!.SelectAll();
    }

    private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Entered {nameof(TextBox_PreviewTextInput)}");

        e.Handled = IntegerPositiveValuesOnlyRegex().IsMatch(e.Text);
    }

    private void TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Entered {nameof(TextBox_PreviewKeyDown)}");

        if (e.Key == Key.Space)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.Back)
        {
            if ((sender as TextBox)!.Text.Length == 1)
            {
                (sender as TextBox)!.SelectAll();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
        {
            if ((sender as TextBox)!.Text.Length == 1)
            {
                (sender as TextBox)!.SelectAll();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Entered {nameof(TextBox_TextChanged)}");

        bool valid = int.TryParse((sender as TextBox)!.Text,
            NumberStyles.Integer,
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            out int validInteger);

        if (valid)
        {
            CustomTextBox.Text = validInteger.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            CustomTextBox.Text = 999.ToString(); // For testing, only, to show there was a problem.
        }
    }

}
```

The IntegerTextBox.xaml

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="SampleTextBoxValidation.Views.CustomControls.IntegerTextBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleTextBoxValidation.Views.CustomControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <!-- Refer to the code behind file to see this user control's logic! -->
    <!-- Binding Value => this is a custom dependency property that is registered to this user control -->
    <!-- RelativeSource => this is needed to enable the databinding in both directions -->
    <TextBox x:Name="CustomIntegerTextBox"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
             Text="{Binding Value, 
                    Mode=TwoWay, 
                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                    ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />

</UserControl>
```

The IntegerTextBox.xaml.cs

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace SampleTextBoxValidation.Views.CustomControls
{
    public partial class IntegerTextBox : UserControl
    {
        [GeneratedRegex("[^0-9]+")]
        private static partial Regex IntegerPositiveValuesOnlyRegex();

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DependencyPropertyOfValue =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Value), typeof(int), typeof(IntegerTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(0));

        public int Value
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(DependencyPropertyOfValue); }
            set { SetValue(DependencyPropertyOfValue, value); }
        }

        public IntegerTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            CustomIntegerTextBox.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
            CustomIntegerTextBox.GotFocus += TextBox_GotFocus;
            CustomIntegerTextBox.PreviewTextInput += TextBox_PreviewTextInput;
            CustomIntegerTextBox.PreviewKeyDown += TextBox_PreviewKeyDown;
        }

        private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Entered {nameof(TextBox_GotFocus)}");

            (sender as TextBox)!.SelectAll();
        }

        private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Entered {nameof(TextBox_PreviewTextInput)}");

            e.Handled = IntegerPositiveValuesOnlyRegex().IsMatch(e.Text);
        }

        private void TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Entered {nameof(TextBox_PreviewKeyDown)}");

            if (e.Key == Key.Space)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            else if (e.Key == Key.Back)
            {
                if ((sender as TextBox)!.Text.Length == 1)
                {
                    (sender as TextBox)!.SelectAll();
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
            else if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
            {
                if ((sender as TextBox)!.Text.Length == 1)
                {
                    (sender as TextBox)!.SelectAll();
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }

        private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Entered {nameof(TextBox_TextChanged)}");

            bool valid = int.TryParse((sender as TextBox)!.Text,
                NumberStyles.Integer,
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                out int validInteger);

            if (valid)
            {
                Value = validInteger;
            }
            else
            {
                Value = 999; // for testing, only, to show an error was not handled
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### <<< Edit after implementing the changes provided by @mm8>>>

So far the passing through of the NotifyDataErrorInfos is working, now.

There is still a issue with data binding, but that is another question.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the Custom IntegerTextBox is showing the red box and not displaying the error message

The difference is that `IntegerTextBox` is a `UserControl` that simply wraps an ordinary `TextBox`. It's not a custom `TextBox`. Your custom `Validation.ErrorTemplate` won't apply to the control.

You should modify your `IntegerTextBox` class to be a custom control that extends `TextBox`. Remove the XAML file and create a stand-alone class:

```
public partial class IntegerTextBox : TextBox
{
    [GeneratedRegex("[^0-9]+")]
    private static partial Regex IntegerPositiveValuesOnlyRegex();

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DependencyPropertyOfValue =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Value), typeof(int), typeof(IntegerTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public int Value
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(DependencyPropertyOfValue); }
        set { SetValue(DependencyPropertyOfValue, value); }
    }

    public IntegerTextBox()
    {
        TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
        GotFocus += TextBox_GotFocus;
        PreviewTextInput += TextBox_PreviewTextInput;
        PreviewKeyDown += TextBox_PreviewKeyDown;
    }

    private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Entered {nameof(TextBox_GotFocus)}");

        (sender as TextBox)!.SelectAll();
    }

    private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Entered {nameof(TextBox_PreviewTextInput)}");

        e.Handled = IntegerPositiveValuesOnlyRegex().IsMatch(e.Text);
    }

    private void TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Entered {nameof(TextBox_PreviewKeyDown)}");

        if (e.Key == Key.Space)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.Back)
        {
            if ((sender as TextBox)!.Text.Length == 1)
            {
                (sender as TextBox)!.SelectAll();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
        {
            if ((sender as TextBox)!.Text.Length == 1)
            {
                (sender as TextBox)!.SelectAll();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Entered {nameof(TextBox_TextChanged)}");

        bool valid = int.TryParse((sender as TextBox)!.Text,
            NumberStyles.Integer,
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            out int validInteger);

        if (valid)
        {
            Value = validInteger;
        }
        else
        {
            Value = 999; // for testing, only, to show an error was not handled
        }
    }
}
```

Then you define a `Style` for the custom control that is based on your `TextBox` style in `TextBoxStyle.xaml`:

```
<Style TargetType="customControls:IntegerTextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}" />
```

Comment: That I will add to my toolbox! Thanks! There is one issue with data binding (I suppose). Please refer to the edit section at the end of my thread. Can you help me with this, also?